# delete files yyyy-mm-dd.pdf more than a month old

Tags: javascript, php

I have pdf files that I want to delete based on the file name that aremore than a month old. For example, if (today - 1 month) is '2022-06-01.pdf' then I want to delete files like '2022-04-13.pdf' and '2021-01-22.pdf'. I don't want to base the selection criteria based on actual date of modification or creation.

**SAMPLE (in temp/)**

```
2019-02-01.pdf  
2020-07-01.pdf  
2021-03-10.pdf  
2021-08-04.pdf  
2022-03-30.pdf
2019-02-27.pdf  
2020-07-08.pdf  
2021-03-17.pdf  
2021-08-11.pdf  
2022-04-06.pdf
```

**HTML**

```
oldFiles(); purgeOLD();
```

**JS**

```
function oldFiles() { // this is ok
yesterday = new Date();
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 30);

actualYear = yesterday.getFullYear();
actualMonth = yesterday.getMonth() + 1;
actualDay = yesterday.getDate();

if (actualMonth < "10") {actualMonth = "0" + actualMonth;}
if (actualDay < "10") {actualDay = "0" + actualDay;}

backtrack = actualYear +'-' +actualMonth +'-' +actualDay;
}

function purgeOLD () { // is this where the problem is ?
var new_data = backtrack; var data; 
$.ajax({url: 'test.php', type: 'post', async: false, data: {user: new_data}});
}
```

**PHP "test.php"**

```
<?php // or is this ?
$result = $_GET['user'];
$rdm = $result .'.pdf';
$glob = glob("temp/2???-??-??.pdf");

foreach($glob as $file) {
if ($file < $rdm) {
{unlink('/home/example/public_html/temp/' .$file ."'"))}    
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Your code sample includes a comment _"is this where the problem is?"_. How would we know? You haven't explained what problem you're facing.

Comment: I'm quite unsure about your approach, your question states you want to delete multiple files, yet your are testing for a file named `YYYY-MM-DD.pdf`, this would mean you only will delete one file as only one file can be named the same in the same directory. A better approach would be to check the modified time of the file in PHP (`filemtime`) and work from there

Comment: The problem is that nothing is happening. The files to be deleted are not deleted.

Comment: Checking the modified time will not work in this instance. I want to delete files yyyy-mm-dd.pdf based on the filename.

Comment: You should first check the modified time then check if the filename matches the pattern imho

Comment: Checking the file modified time won't work because the files get modified a new date which may spoils the search criteria.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing in jQuery code, you can do straightforward in PHP without any input from ajax/jquery like this:https://3v4l.org/pKrnt

Comment: That would be a disaster as ALL the older files would be deleted. I want to delete the older '2???-mm-dd.pdf' files.

Comment: IMO this question needs more focus. Is this a JavaScript question (does the PHP code work) or is this a PHP question (then the JavaScript code is irrelevant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this entirely server-side.

1. Construct a `DateTime` instance for *"1 month ago"*
2. Create a filename from that instance
3. Iterate the files and compare the [basename](https://www.php.net/manual/function.basename.php) (ignoring any directory prefix)
4. If the filename represents a date prior to *"1 month ago"*, delete it

```php
$lastMonth = new DateTimeImmutable('-1 month');
$cutoff = sprintf('%s.pdf', $lastMonth->format('Y-m-d'));

$glob = glob("temp/2???-??-??.pdf");

foreach($glob as $file) {
    if (basename($file) < $cutoff) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `new \DateTimeImmutable('-1 month')` ? :D

Comment: @emix nothing, I don't use PHP regularly now and have forgotten some of the tricks

Comment: It's interesting how people tend to remember about specific methods, time intervals and their formats, but don't remember simple stuff ;)

Comment: Thank you so much. What I learned was that most, if not all server-side operations are best handled in the domain of php.